# Android: Layout is different in Eclipse & Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a layout with the Graphical layout in Eclipse,

**What I see in Eclipse**

[image: this is how I see it in Eclipse]

the .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="@string/emptyString"></AutoCompleteTextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/toString" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.33333333" android:id="@+id/buttonContacts" android:text="@string/contactsString" android:textSize="17sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.33333333" android:id="@+id/buttonGroups" android:text="@string/groupsString" android:textSize="17sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:text="@string/favouritesString" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonFavourites" android:layout_weight="0.33333333" android:textSize="17sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/repetition" android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
        <Spinner android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/spinner" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:prompt="@string/repetition" android:layout_below="@+id/textView3" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Spinner>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2" android:textSize="17sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.50" android:text="@string/button_ok"></Button>
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:textSize="17sp" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/button_cancel"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/messageString" android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/button_time" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/background_black" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_below="@+id/spinner" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/button_date" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/background_black" android:id="@+id/imageButton2" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="60dp"></ImageButton>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="top|left" android:layout_height="110dp">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**this is how I see it in the emulator when the app starts**

[image: this is how I see it in the emulator when the app starts]

**this is how I see it in the emulator after I change what I choose in the list**

[image: this is how I see it in the emulator after I change what I choose in the list]

Any idea what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference to id there should not be a "+" there.
This is bad:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
```

This is good:

```
android:layout_below="@id/editText1"
```

Use "@+id/..." only in element definition.

Comment: Just created the layout, didn't get the chance to edit the id's.
but I don't think it's the problem...

Comment: ADT isn't the most stable tool. You usually have to edit the xmls on your own.